# how to classify the following statement?

Tags: logic

How would you classify the following condition $p(x)$ when $x\in \mathbb{R}$:

$p(x):\left(\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, a(x^3+8)=0\right)\Rightarrow x+2=0$

is it Universal, Possible but not universal or Impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This is equivalent to $$x^3+8 = 0 \implies x+2 = 0$$

Comment: so, since there is only one value of $x$ that works, we can say it is possible but not universal. Right? 

The problem I have is with that $a$, but when we classify $p(x)$ it should be according to $x$, Correct?

Comment: @Concept7, the $a$ is just a dumby variable; it doesn't actually "feature" in the final meaning of the expression. Anyway, it's Universal. There's two cases to check: you need to check the case $x=-2$, and the case $x \neq -2$. In both cases, the expression will evaluate to TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

As *goblin* has already said, it is universal. Although only one value of $x$ makes both equations true, all values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ make the conditional true. Here is a step by step proof:

Let $x$ be any real value and assume

$$\forall a\in \mathbb{R}, a (x^3 + 8) = 0$$

From this it follows (by instantiating, taking $1$ for $a$):

$$x^3 + 8 = 0$$

Since $x$ was assumed to be a real number, this equation has only one solution:

$$x = -2$$

Therefore

$$x + 2 = 0$$

and the conditional

$$\left(\forall a\in \mathbb{R}, a (x^3 + 8) = 0\right) \Rightarrow x + 2 = 0$$

comes out true. Since we have asssumed of $x$ only that it is a real number, we can generalize to

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:\left[\left(\forall a\in \mathbb{R}, a (x^3 + 8) = 0\right) \Rightarrow x + 2 = 0\right]$$

Hence, your condition is universal for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It is merely possible, of course, when $x$ is not restricted to real numbers.